# Vertx - Restrict Upload file type

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm creating an API using Vertx to let user upload images but I want to restrict to certain file types - `jpg|Jpeg|png`.

What's the best way to do this?

```
private void uploadLogoHandler(RoutingContext context) {
   //Filter content type

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

`<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*" />`

On vert.x we need to check the content type of uploaded file, assuming we will have only one upload:

```
Set<FileUpload> fileUploads = routingContext.fileUploads();
FileUpload fileUpload = fileUploads.iterator().next();
fileUpload.contentType();
if(!fileUpload.contentType().startsWith("image/")){
    routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("Please upload an image.");
}else{
    // Process your image
}
```

Comment: This will work but the file will be upload and processed by the server, if you really want to avoid that work you should add a handler before the `BodyHandler` with the check you're doing here, if the content type matches, then continue, else terminate the request with a 400 status code (Bad Request) or something more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: But that will become generic for all file uploads, I don't know exact requirement but yes you can do it using `router.route("/*").handler( ur handler );`

Comment: will this recognize a file that "pretends" to be an image, but is not?  I think you need to actually scan the file to verify that it is the correct type.  No?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a "best" way to do it.  But here are some options

[1] on the client, look at the extension of the file before you allow the user to upload it (hide the final upload button and only show it after they select a filename with the correct extension).  You can do this in client side javascript, you can't access the full path of the file, but you can access the name of the file (minus the path).

[2] Do the same as the above on the server.  You should be able to grab the name of the file in the muti-part uplaod.

[3] There is no easy way to check what the actual file type is while the upload is in progress.  What I would do (if you are checking for an image) is write it to a temp file and then run Java ImageIO to read the image.  If it reads without error, then it is an image, if not, you will get an exception, and delete the file.  I am not aware of a security problems of doing this.  Note that reading the file via ImageIO is a blocking operation, so put it in a vert.x execute blocking.